# Image display from sd card

Tags: android, android-image, android-sdcard

I am new to Android. In my app, I want to access a particular image from my sd card. But the image is not displayed. I have include WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE request in my manifest.

```
public class Display extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final TextView name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    final TextView phone_no=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone_no);

    File f= new File("/storage/sdcard0/Download/images.jpeg");
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
}
```

I also tried the following codes, but of no use

```
File mFichier = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/storage/sdcard0/Download/images.jpeg");

    if(mFichier.exists())
    {
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(mFichier));
    }
```

and also this code

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/sdcard0/Download/images.jpeg"); 
imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
```

Please help me as to why my image is not getting displayed..

Comment: you should not hard code the path. use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and instead of `/` this use `File.Seperator`.

Comment: have you checked that f.exists()?

Comment: is "/mnt" necessary in the path?

Comment: @Andro external directory path changes from one android version to another, one device to another. You should only `context.getExternalFilesDir()` which will return your app's external files directory.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will try n let u know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you want to load file from external storage like sdcard, you'd better use following code:

```
public File getDataFolder(Context context) {
    File dataDir = null;
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            dataDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myappdata");
            if(!dataDir.isDirectory()) {
                dataDir.mkdirs();
            }
        }

        if(!dataDir.isDirectory()) {
            dataDir = context.getFilesDir();
        }

    return dataDir;
}
```

It will return a folder which is named "myappdata" located in your sd-card. After that, if you want to load a image from that folder, you can use following code:

```
File cacheDir = getDataFolder(this);
File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, "images.jpeg");
InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(cacheFile);
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = scale;
bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap wallpaperBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream, null, bitmapOptions);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.preview);
imageView.setImageBitmap(wallpaperBitmap);
```

If you still have problem with above code, you can check the full example here:

[Android Save And Load Downloading File Locally](http://jmsliu.com/1954/android-save-downloading-file-locally.html)